# Google Analytics not counting page views and audience data of my website?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

My clients has two websites & more then 6 months Google Analytics doesn't show any audience & others visitors data even Real time data. But at Google Search Console is data about organic query & also others. Also some of the keywords already rank at google 1st page. At this time what can I do to get solution about the problem.

Comment: If it isn't showing realtime data then it isn't installed correctly.

Comment: But I had seen real time data before 6 months & nowadays doesn't show data. Need to reinstall Google Analytics?

Comment: What Stephen said. Try to troubleshoot with Google Tag Assistant Chrome add-on, and make sure the code is on every page you need to track. (Sometimes, due to website changes, plugin updates, etc. the code can fall off.)

Comment: It is certainly worth check if the snippet is installed.   It is also possible you added a filter to Google Analytics that is filtering out everything.